cURL/API body request fails in local, Postman and production NextJS app but works in other environments (reqbin, hoppscotch)
I'm currently developing a mobile app that will have user purchases in it's interface. The payment flow occurs as follows: the user enters payment data in the appropriate fields in the application. When confirming the purchase, an API request is sent to our server, so that it can be redirected to the payment gateway of a partner company of ours. The server authenticates with the gateway, receives the success response, and then sends a new payment request to the gateway, using the encrypted authentication token, carrying the user's payment information. If the response is a success, then the success screen is displayed on the phone. The main problem is: the authentication request returns successfully and the auth token is generated successfully. However, the billing request returns the error "Invalid login data, please authenticate". And this is not a gateway's error fault!
I did obtain the request's body cURL to test the API in different scenarios and observed that in two online test environments (https://reqbin.com/curl and https://hoppscotch.io/), the response was obtained successfully, while on the production server (Vercel), in my local environment (VSCode) and in postman (https://www.postman.com/), the response returned with the error presented. The gateway company's software engineers and I have reviewed the requests, logs, and code, and we were unable to pinpoint any errors. They were able to run cURL in Apple's terminal environment, though.
When researching, I found information that the operating system's language formatting should be in UTF-8, otherwise there would be side effects on requests. However, I don't believe this is the problem, since the authentication body returns success in all attempts, while the payments body returns an error. And other testers can run the same requests as me.
Below, I am leaving an exact copy of the request body used in the tests, but with the credentials hidden for obvious reasons.
The authentication request:
(Always returns success)
const authResponse = await fetch(authUrl, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        accept: "application/json",
        "X-Credential-Type": "authenticate",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        authorization: `Basic ${base64Credentials}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email: ******,
        senha: ******,
    }),
});

The billing request:
const transactionResponse = await fetch(transactionUrl, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        authorization: `Basic ${base64AuthForTransaction}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        parcelas: 1,
        valor: 100.0,
        tipo: "PIX",
        card_number: "*********",
        card_holder_name: "*******",
        card_expires: "****",
        card_cvv: "***",
        client_ip: "***.***.**.***"
    }),
});

"base64AuthForTransaction" is the result of getting the token returned from authResponse object, than transforming into a SHA1 HMAC string, then converting to base64 string, concatenating the "credential_email:sha1=hmac_token".
The cURL which worked for Reqbin and Hoppscotch, but will not work for local, postman or production:
curl --location '***********' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic ***********' \
--data '{
   "empresa":{
      "id":"************************"
   },
   "parcelas":1,
   "valor":100.0,
   "tipo":"PIX",
   "card_number":"*********",
   "card_holder_name":"*******",
   "card_expires":"****",
   "card_cvv":"***",
   "client_ip":"***.***.**.***"
}'

As I have said at the top: the other engineers did execute the same requests on their OS, so it's not any additional character like spaces or missing letters. Also it is not related to wrong credentials. The auth request is executed fine, but the billing request only works on specific environments.
My goal here is to be able to execute the billing requests from my production server on Vercel. Hopefully someone is able to help me solve this.
